# Does vyper's `send` function have the same issue as solidity's `transfer`?

Tags: transfer, vyper

In `solidity` it's bad practice to use the `transfer` keyword because [of how gas costs are subject to change, and the transfer function has it's gas costs hard-coded](https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/).

Does [vyper's send](https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/built-in-functions.html?highlight=send#send) suffer the same issue?